# How to use generic list for putParcelableArrayList?

Tags: android, kotlin, bundle

Using kotlin, and having a function takes a generic list,  and inside the lis is put in a Bundle to pass to a fragment.

```
fun createArgs(filters: List<Filters>?): Bundle {
    val args = Bundle()
    args.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_FILTERS, filters)  //<=== does not compile
```

has to change to

```
args.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_FILTERS, ArrayList(filters))
```

which making another copy of the list.

How to set a generic list into Bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases (but not always) `List` instances are actually `ArrayList`s. So you can avoid most copies:

```
fun <T> List<T>.asArrayList(): ArrayList<T> = if (this is ArrayList) this else ArrayList(this)

args.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_FILTERS, filters.asArrayList())
```

Bundle won't mutate the list you put into it, so this should be safe enough assuming *you* don't mutate it either after putting it into the bundle.

Answer (score 3):

> How to set a generic list into Bundle?

You don't. `Bundle` is limited to only certain types, and `List` is not one of them.

Comment: thx @CommonsWare, so it means cannt use the generic list or have to make a copy (that is in our case the function is derived from a 3rd party and cant change to passing in ArrayList<>)? Just dont want copy it again, hmm.